# What precisely is a "trailing space" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I am working on a project where I have to make sure that I do not store strings in the MySQL 5.5 database back-end which have what the MySQL documentation calls "trailing spaces" (this is mainly due to the [oddities with `char` and `varchar` fields, unique indexes and comparisons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html)).

That basically means that the application must remove "trailing spaces" from all strings before storing them in the database. While this is easy at the first sight, I am asking myself what (trailing) spaces exactly are in this context.

Of course, ASCII 0x20 is a space. But there are many other (unicode) characters which usually are considered spaces (at least, outside the MySQL world). Examples would be U+00A0 (non-break space) and U+200B (zero-width space), to name two of them; I am quite sure that there are at least a dozen others of them.

I am very strongly assuming that MySQL in the context mentioned above considers only the usual space char (ASCII 0x20) as space, but nevertheless I would like to know for sure. I haven't seen hints regarding this in the MySQL documentation or at other places, so I'm asking here.

Comment: Your safest bet is probably `RTRIM(value)` as that automatically updates with MySQL's definition of "trailing space".

Comment: @Marvin Thanks for the suggestion and +1. But for certain reasons, I'd like to let the application do as much work as possible (including trimming). Furthermore, I am generally interested in the answer to that question. Do we have to look up some SQL specification for getting this answered?

Comment: MySQL will only remove that single ascii 0x20 character ("space"), no other unicode values (that aren't called space, but "<insert type> space"). That being said, although unlikely, there is no guarantee that it will not change at some point - but it will be certainly be documented. Unfortunately, looking at the sql standard will not help you, as `rtrim` and `ltrim` are no standard functions anyway (although it defines "space" as the default for `trim`). But eventually you will have to look into the source code, trust the internet or test the (limited amount of) unicode spaces.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you! That is what I was thinking. Regarding the second part of your comment: AFAIK, cutting the trailing spaces when comparing is part of the *SQL standard*, even if ltrim and rtrim are not. So I had the hope that this standard might exactly define what characters are considered space characters. Testing all unicode space characters is a thing which I'd like to avoid because I never can be sure that I really test *all* of them. After all, if the SQL standard does not define it, it's up to MySQL to (arbitrarily) decide what is considered a space character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, both the final draft for SQL:2006, Part 2 and a later (non-final) working draft for a later SQL version contain a similar passage which deals with that subject.

From the first one (chapter 4.2.1, Introduction to character strings, emphasis mine):

> Character sets fall into three categories: those defined by national
>   or international standards, those defined by SQL-implementations, and
>   those defined by applications. The character sets defined by
>   [ISO10646] and [Unicode] are known as Universal Character Sets (UCS)
>   and their treatment is described in Subclause 4.2.8, “Universal
>   character sets”. **Every character set contains the <space> character
>   (equivalent to U+0020).** An application defines a character set by
>   assigning a new name to a character set from one of the first two
>   categories. They can be defined to “reside” in any schema chosen by
>   the application. Character sets defined by standards or by
>   SQL-implementations reside in the Information Schema (named
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA) in each catalog, as do collations defined by
>   standards and collations, transliterations, and transcodings defined
>   by SQLimplementations.

IMHO, this leaves no doubt that ASCII 0x20 is the *only* thing which the SQL standard (and thus MySQL) considers <space>, notably when taking into account that both the standard and the MySQL documentation write that character as shown, i.e. including the angle brackets.